# Update Shadow view in Drag and Drop

Tags: java, android, kotlin, layout, android-recyclerview

I use the drag and drop API in a RecyclerView with a shadow. I wanted to know if is it possible to update the shadow (like height/width or whatever) according to the drag event ?

For exemple, when the drag action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED, I want to resize the shadow.

Thank you for your answers !

Answer (score 0):

You could change your dropable view background in DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED case like this:

```
v.setBackgroundDrawable(shadowDrawable);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this modify the dropable view. That I want is to modify the dragged view (the shadow passed in the ```ViewCompat.startDragAndDrop()```

Comment: shadowBuilder.getView().setBackground(shadowDrawable); @Ady